# Calling goodness of fit value with result.prsquared() in statsmodels results TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Tags: python, object, typeerror, statsmodels

I am a complete beginner, and I'm currently doing this tutorial about logit regression models in python 3.4, with statsmodels 0.6.1 and Pycharm community version 4.5.1:

http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/logistic-regression-and-python.html

It runs smoothly. I try to add my own lines, to try out a few things.

After the part when I fit the data

```
train_cols = data.columns[1:]
logit = sm.logit(data['admit'], data[train_cols])
result = logit.fit()
```

and I print out the summary

```
print(result.summary())
```

I tried to take a little detour from the tutorial, to print only the Goodness of Fit measurement (in this case, it is a pseudo R-squared value). According to the [documentation](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.LogitResults.html#statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.LogitResults) it is a method of result object (same as summary), so it should work like this:

```
print(result.prsquared())
```

However, running this code results in a TypeError on a line containing only print(result.prsquared()):

> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

It really bugs me, because if I would to compare several models, pseudo R-squared would be my first choice to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prsquared is an *attribute*, not a function. Try:

```
print(result.prsquared)
```

Comment: It's a cached property, which is accessed like an attribute, but sphinx doesn't render it in the documentation without the parentheses.